# Ruby Passenger wont start

Tags: ruby, passenger

I was tasked with upgrading the ruby installation on a machine the other day. I installed from source (typically ./configure, make, make install) and updated all gems. Currently, the site won't load with a Ruby Rack error, which I have no idea how to solve:

```
[ pid=21855 thr=104368260 file=utils.rb:176 time=2013-02-19 11:33:32.952 ]: *** Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)) (process 21855, thread #<Thread:0x0000000c711108>):
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-flash-0.1.2/lib/rack/flash.rb:20:in `run'
        from config.ru:7:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:225:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:225:in `load_rack_app'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:157:in `block in initialize_server'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:563:in `report_app_init_status'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:154:in `initialize_server'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Have any of you seen this type of error before? Any thoughts on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. When looking at the error, I noticed that the first module in the trace is `rack-flash`. Turns out that the new verison of it is incompatible with `sinatra` which this app is also using. I commented out the flash related code and the app runs.

Now I just need to figure out the proper way to port the flash related code to `sinatra-flash` and I think I'm good to go.